# What is Rey's staff?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

If Rey's staff (and others like it, such as the scavenger that tries to kidnap BB8) is just an ordinary staff, then why is it all techy looking?

What exactly is this staff, just techy looking sections or something more?

Comment: My personal assumption is that it's just a scavenged bit of metal from something, and made into a staff. However, some members have *The Visual Dictionary* and I hope it has an answer!

Comment: Very possible... mine was created after at the same time.

Comment: @CreationEdge no I wrote my question in response to that one. Mine asks more generally what are the staffs and what are they for?

Comment: @Escoce Yes, but the answer addresses your question. And and answer of "No" to that other question with any explanation at all would also be an answer to this question (as seen already).

Answer (score 1):

Rey seems to support herself by scavenging nearby wrecks. The staff is most likely a conveniently sized section of pipe/support/conduit she found while hunting for more valuable salvage.

Comment: I would go with this answer and wouldn't have even asked except that everyone who has a staff seems to have nearly the same thing, as well as mentioned in a previous question, the sections resemble light sabers.

Comment: Another question features a picture from the Visual Dictionary where the staff is labeled as "scavenged staff" (would link or edit the answer but I'm on my phone). As for the appearance, it should be noted that fx guys are notorious reusers of parts (remember the Milennium Falcon as part of a building in Blade Runner?) It is certainly conceivable that they simply built the staff out of spare greebles they had laying around, including light saber parts.